# Возможно ли сверстать такой border. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: html, css, css3, border

Просто не понимаю, как можно сверстать рамку с таким пересечением, перечитала все, что можно, но ничего[image: введите сюда описание изображения] не смогла сделать

Comment: Да просто картинку на фон поставить и всё, чё мучаться

Comment: А если хочется адаптивность по ширине/высоте, можно нарезать на пять картинок и поставить пять фонов (два для углов и три для сторон)

Comment: я бы углы сделал линиями на CSS

Comment: Но вообще Евгений Иванов действительно обратил моё внимание на несоответствие текста вопроса "такое пересечение" и заголовка "такой border". Так что автору стоит уточнить, что же он имеет в виду и какой ответ хочет, иначе вопрос придётся закрыть как слишком неконкретный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так можно:

```css
.box {
    padding: 0 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.box::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    transform: skewX(-70deg);
}

.box-inner {
    padding: 30px 30px 60px;
}

.box-inner::before,
.box-inner::after {
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.box-inner::before {
    left: 40px;
}

.box-inner::after {
    right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed felis nisi. Phasellus faucibus bibendum lorem. Donec placerat, risus et lacinia imperdiet, risus elit finibus lacus, vitae dapibus nulla sem id dolor.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасиибо большое*-*

Comment: Пожалуйста! Нажмите галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Минус за несоответствие картинке из вопроса.

Comment: @andreymal В чем именно несоответствие? Вы ожидали точного сходства?

Comment: @Neolot разумеется, иначе просто убивается вся дизайнерская задумка. Вместо плавных закругленных концов, изображённых на картинке, вы сделали ровный острый срез через skew, что вопиюще некорректно и даже может изменить визуальное настроение страницы.

Comment: @andreymal я почему то вашего варианта точно соответствующего макету нигде не увидел. А вот критики и минусов под каждым ответом хватает.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов и это даёт другим право клепать заведомо неверные ответы? Не переводите стрелки, не разводите демагогию, не уводите тему. То, что этот вариант некорректен, никак не зависит от наличия или отсутствия других вариантов.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов и свой вариант я кстати уже написал в самом первом комментарии к вопросу, вам нужно читать внимательнее.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто попробовал как-то

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

footer {
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.footer__container_1 {
  padding: 0 45px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.footer__icon {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 30px;
}

.footer__container_1::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1) skewX(-70deg);
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #6b6363;
  bottom: -25px;
}

.footer__container::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 250%;
  left: -10px;
  top: -50%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #6b6363;
}

.footer__container::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 250%;
  right: -10px;
  top: -50%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #6b6363;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="footer__container_1">
      <div class="footer__container">
        <div class="footer__icon">
          <img class="footer_img" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/515/515094.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icon">
          0+
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icon">
          6+
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icon">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2943/2943909.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icon">
          12+
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icon">
          16+
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icon">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/900/900930.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: И тоже вопиюще некорректный skew, как и в соседнем ответе.

Comment: @andreymal тоже так считаю, но не додумался особо как сделать без sker, border-radius не сильно закругляет

Answer (score -1):

Может так?

```css
.el {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px
}

.el:after, .el:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0
}

.el:before {
    left: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000
}

.el:after {
    top: -30px;
    bottom: -30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: спасиииииибо*-*

Comment: Даже отдалённо не похоже на то, что на картинке.

Comment: тут главное принцип

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов этот принцип не позволит сделать border как на картинке. Принцип важен, и в вашем ответе принцип неверен. (В других ответах принципы тоже не верны, кстати.)

Comment: @andreymal судя по комментарию автора вопроса, этого было достаточно ;)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов если работу автора будет кто-то проверять, то за использование любого из предложенных здесь ответов такую работу отклонят из-за несоответствия макету.

Comment: @andreymal вопрос автора прочитайте пожалуйста внимательно. "как можно сверстать рамку с таким пересечением" все ответы соответствуют вопросу. 
Дело то в простой справдливости. Вы сами написав лишь "сделай картинкой" заминусовали всех ответивших. Не красиво. И странно что не можете этого признать. Вроде авторитетный человек тут.
PS: про соответствие макету ни слова кстати в вопросе.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов и вы тоже прочитайте вопрос целиком, в заголовке написано "сверстать такой border". Установка картинки на фон позволяет сделать такой border, всё хорошо. А если вы осознанно не хотите соответствовать макету, когда просят "сверстать такой border", то мне, видимо, опять придётся на Мете поднимать тему вредительства отдельных участников ruSO.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов и даже просто пересечение в вашем ответе сделано не "такое", так что ваш ответ неверен даже в вашей интерпретации вопроса.

Comment: @andreymal в общем странный вы человек. Я вам про справедливость и ваши действия, а вы мне про свое видение вопроса. Да и фиг бы с ним вашим видением. Но все ответы УСТРОИЛИ автора вопроса что очевидно по её ответам ;)
А пугать не надо. Хотите - поднимайте вопросы где хотите ) Больше реагировать на вас не планирую ;)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов тогда вопрос просто должен быть закрыт. Да и вообще вопросы-картинки обычно и так закрывают.